# Retrieving the geo location(region or continent) from an IP address using SparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a table column with a set of IP addresses and I need to find out its Region/Continent as described below.

```
------------------------------------------------------
ip_address      |    region
------------------------------------------------------
217.100.34.222  |   North Holland
```

For this purpose I have downloaded a IP-Country-Region-City database from [ip2location.com](http://ip2location.com) but its tables and values shows as follows.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
ip_from  | ip_to  | country_code  |  country_name  | region_name  |  city_name
-----------------------------------------------------
16777216 | 16777471 | AU          | Australia      | Queensland   | Brisbane
```

How would I be able to convert my `ip_address` column into a `decimal number` as shown in the ip2location database and to retrieve the data out of it or is there a better way to do this process in order to retrieve the `geo location` from the `ip address`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> better way to do this process in order to retrieve the geo location
>   from the ip address using SparkSQL?

**Option 1**:

As described by databricks on ad analytics, its one way. Please check the complete article - [an-illustrated-guide-to-advertising-analytics.html](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/02/an-illustrated-guide-to-advertising-analytics.html)

Web service call directly from Spark:

```
# Obtain the unique agents from the accesslog table
ipaddresses = sqlContext.sql("select distinct ip1 from \
 accesslog where ip1 is not null").rdd
# getCCA2: Obtains two letter country code based on IP address
def getCCA2(ip):
  url = 'http://freegeoip.net/csv/' + ip
  str = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
  return str.split(",")[1]
# Loop through distinct IP addresses and obtain two-letter country codes
mappedIPs = ipaddresses.map(lambda x: (x[0], getCCA2(x[0])))
```

two letter country codes can be expanded by lookup later

**Option 2**: Hive table approach like example with scala pseudo code (instead of web service approach.)

Ingest data to hive tables as you have already downloaded.

```
val ipsdf = hiveContext.sql(s"select ip from iptable ")
val countriesWithIp = hiveContext.sql(s"select countryname,ip from countriesWithIPs")

countriesWithIpAddrMapped = ipsdf.join(countriesWithIp , ipsdf("ip")===countriesWithIp("ip"), "inner" )

countriesWithIpAddrMapped.show();
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it without using any webservices?

Comment: AFAIK there might be.. you can download ip and corresponding country code and put in hive table and look up. That will work.

Comment: instead of using webservice call you can put the data in to hive table and use `hiveContext.sql(s"select country from your table where ip =$ip" )`

Comment: You solution seems to be fine, but just one question, how to do the join function as there are two columns that must be checked :
ip_from  and  ip_to  ??

Comment: use hive table approach if  you feel its very convenient way i.e. option 2

Comment: I have created two dataframes for both tables (CSV files), I used your solution using join function : val test = df1.join(df2,df1("_c0") === df2("value"), "inner")
 but it only checks the columns based on the fixed numbers  and not ip range. For example, to check  this ip "16777218", it does not return any value since it cannot check the range 16777216 to 16777471

Comment: if I understand your problem correctly you want to join 2 ips ipfrom ipto that is a join. now the problem is you want to join ip1 is falling under range of ip addresses. ***now its not join any more*** its a lookup. you can proceed with `isin` column function or spark udf with condition (ipToTest >= ipLo && ipToTest <= ipHi)  with this. Or else use a static table which has already defined IP addresses in hive. I hope that helps. still not okay, please raise another question.

Comment: thank you for your response, actually, I have two tables, one including the ip addresses, the other includes the ip range and country name :

ip_from  |    ip_to  |     country name :

16777216 | 16777471   |   Australia 

I have created dataframe for each tables , first table got 80 records including only ips, and my question is how can I get country name from the second table?

Comment: Pls post another question in SO

Comment: ok see here please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674339/retrieving-the-ip-geo-location