# Retrieving the IP geo location

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two .CSV files, one including IP addresses :

- 76.83.179.64
- 76.83.179.64
- 187.42.62.209
- 89.142.219.5

and the other includes IP ranges and country names as follow:

```
 ip_from|  ip_to|  country_name|    

|16777216|16777471|Australia|
```

What I have done so far is as follow:

load the data : ip_from, ip_to and country name

```
val rdd1 = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", 
"true").load("/FileStore/tables/locations.CSV")
val df2 = rdd1.toDF()
```

load the data and converts from IP to Long

```
val rdd2 = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/ipaddress.csv")
def ipToLong(ipAddress: String): Long = {
ipAddress.split("\\.").reverse.zipWithIndex
.map(a=>a._1.toInt*math.pow(256,a._2).toLong).sum
}
val df1 = rdd2.map(x=>ipToLong(x)).toDF()
```

Now, what user defined function should I write to join both DFs(or look up) and retrieve the country name according the ip address?

Comment: you should join then using range function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your case you simply use following logic

```
df1.join(df2, df1("value") >= df2("ip_from") && df1("value") <= df2("ip_to"), "left")
```

Comment: I think it should be &&

Comment: @user3616059, I have edited my answer :) you can accept and upvote if the answer helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left_outer` join along with a `UDF` that does the ip-to-long conversion like in the following example:

```
val dfIP = Seq(
  ("76.83.179.64"),
  ("76.83.179.64"),
  ("187.42.62.209"),
  ("89.142.219.5")
).toDF("ip")

val dfRange = Seq(
  (1000000000L, 1500000000L, "Country A"),
  (1500000000L, 3000000000L, "Country B"),
  (3000000000L, 4000000000L, "Country C")
).toDF("ip_from", "ip_to", "country_name")

def ipToLong = udf(
  (ip: String) =>
    ip.split("\\.").reverse.zipWithIndex.map(
      a => a._1.toInt * math.pow(256,a._2).toLong
    ).sum
)

val dfJoined = dfIP.join(
  dfIPRange,
  ipToLong($"ip") >= $"ip_from" && ipToLong($"ip") < $"ip_to",
  "left_outer"
)

dfJoined.show
+-------------+----------+----------+------------+
|           ip|   ip_from|     ip_to|country_name|
+-------------+----------+----------+------------+
| 76.83.179.64|1000000000|1500000000|   Country A|
| 76.83.179.64|1000000000|1500000000|   Country A|
|187.42.62.209|3000000000|4000000000|   Country C|
| 89.142.219.5|1500000000|3000000000|   Country B|
+-------------+----------+----------+------------+
```